# Is it safe to touch a 220/120V gate door lock transformer with my bare hands?

Tags: transformer, smart

I use a transformer that takes **220/120V AC** input and outputs **12/24V AC** to the gate door lock to open it remotely with an intercom.

I need to add a smart switch to the gate and I have to get the transformer out with my **hands** to add the extra wires.

Dimension of the transformer are about: **10 cm** length, width and height.

Is it **safe** to touch it with my bare hands? if not, can I wear **gloves** and take it out? Also, I currently don't have access to the **power breaker** to turn the power off.

This is a picture of the transformer I have:

[image]

Comment: Wait until you can switch it off at the breaker, then I suggest that you leave a note on the breaker not to switch it on because someone is working on the circuit, and check at the transformer that the mains really is switched off.

Comment: Is the transformer earthed solidly? Do you have residual current breakers installed? How thick are your gloves and what are they made from? Personally, this looks like the original installation was made by someone unqualified.

Comment: @Andyaka no it isn't earthed, I don't think there's an earth wire for it. I cannot reach the breaker right now. my gloves the ones used for car mechanical work, about 3-4 mm think maybe

Comment: @AndrewMorton I totally agree, but even that didn't stop some idiot foreman from turning a circuit back on that a friend of mine was working on. It was only that he caught a transformer starting to hum that warned him of the danger. "Oh, I thought you had finished"  said the foreman, so my friend decked him and walked off the site. The moral is, wherever possible put the fuses in your pocket and take them away until you've completed the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is No!
Picking it up and moving it, like you have apparently already done, is marginally OK if you handle it by the frame or core but this assumes the transformer has no insulation faults or leakage from the windings to the metalwork. I wouldn't do it unless there was no alternative. Live working is for experts only. Those with the correct training and equipment. There is no way anyone here is going to tell you to work on a live transformer.

Comment: But that's just a heat sink around it right? the metal part. Why is it not safe to touch it?

Comment: @JohnSall No there's no heat sink. The parts you can see are 4 blue/green brackets that are for mounting it (in a box?) One also holds the blue terminal strip. They bolt onto the core, the stack of metal plates that concentrate the magnetic field and which pass through the plastic bobbin onto which are wound the primary (mains) and secondary windings. If everything is OK, it is dry and undamaged mechanically, by heat and by ageing then touching the transformer may be OK. But working on the wiring is different, don't do it whilst it is live.

Comment: @JohnSall The other problem is in the picture. The transformer is dusty and appears to have been mounted in the hole in the wall behind it. We have no way of telling if this is indoors or outside, a dry or damp environment. Or generally what state the transformer is in or how long it's been there.

Comment: It's a villa with a brick fence, and there's a gate in the fence, you might see it in the picture on the left. So it's an outdoor and the transformer is inside the wall and then there's a wire running from the transformer to the door lock at the left. it's been there installed for 10 years now

Comment: can I just know worst thing can happen to me while wearing cotton gloves and wearing shoes?

Comment: Worst thing? You get electrocuted. There’s also the potential of arc flash. Getting a face full of vaporized metal rarely has a positive outcome. Cotton gloves didn’t save Michael Jackson nor will they protect you against electrocution.

Comment: @JohnSall the problem with statements like "it's just a heat sink" (or mounting bracket in this case) is even though the mounting bracket isn't supposed to be electrified, *sometimes things go wrong and it is*.  Even professional electricians will always turn off the power if they don't need it to be on, before working on a circuit. Usually if the bracket got somehow electrified, it would cause a short circuit because it would be grounded by a metal box. But it's not in a metal box, is it, it's sitting on what looks like a stone countertop. You can never be too careful.

Comment: @JohnSall obviously us internet hecklers can't stop you from playing with the transformer and you have a quite good chance of being just fine - after all it's not designed to electrocute people - but *in the off-chance it's not fine* then nobody here is responsible because we did warn you that there was a chance it might not be fine. That chance is why you should turn the power off.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that picture...

- It looks like the transformer has an earthing/grounding lug on it, but nobody has bothered to use it.  If the transformer is working perfectly, and ian't damp, then the metal frame probably isn't live.  But if it's damaged, nobody knows.
- The incoming live wires have only "basic insulation" - a single layer of insulation, not insulated and sheathed.  If that single layer of insulation is good, it's probably safe.
- There's nothing to stop you poking a screwdriver into the live terminals, if you can't turn the power off.
- The outgoing wires have only very thin insulation, and the sheath has been cut back leaving long sections of the low voltage wires exposed.  These are in the same containment as the 220/120V wire, but they aren't insulated to that standard.

It's one of those cases where it probably won't kill you if you work on it.  But I wouldn't want to do a job on the basis that I *probably* won't die.

If live working is absolutely necessary, then you should have the correct personal protective equipment (PPE) for it.  And it doesn't sound like you have any of that.

Comment: The thin 4-wire cable at the back right (orange / red / blue / green twisted quad? in a white outer sheath) looks like telephone house wiring cable to me and possibly forms part of an intercom, not the gate operating  system. But it may have been misused as such. There is a single grey wire on the left which might be significant. In my opinion this setup looks as if it was installed by an amateur who didn't know much about electrical safety.

Comment: @PeterJennings Yeah, those are cat6 wires that are used, and they go to the intercom to power the gate lock as a switch. Also, the grey wire on the left is also a cat6 wires that has grey cover over it, and it's also going to the intercom outside unit to complete the switch. The two black thick wires are the live 220V wires.

Comment: Since I don't have access to the breaker, is it a good idea to install an outdoor switch next to the transformer, and connect that switch to one wire of the black live wires? And so, whenever I want to work, instead of turning off the breaker, I just turn off the switch. I can use a normal light bulb switch there.

Comment: @JohnSall If you don't have access to the breaker then installing a switch is still live working. Please don't do it. If you do install a switch it should be a double pole one that breaks both the black wires and should be mounted in a proper weatherproof enclosure along with the transformer and any other equipment that needs to be outside. Not just a hole hacked in the wall.